# Xamarin Forms UI Thread not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a countdown timer inside a thread that will be updated in the UI of my application.
I have a problem using the reference `System.Threading.Thread.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
           {
                this.timer1 = this.timer1.AddDays(16);
               this.timer1 = this.timer1.AddMonths(10);
               this.timer1 = this.timer1.AddYears(2015);

               this.timer2 = DateTime.Now;


               this.result = this.timer1.Subtract(this.timer2);

               nbJour = this.result.Days.ToString();
               nbHeure = this.result.Hours.ToString();
               nbMin = this.result.Minutes.ToString();

           });

        })).Start();
```

`Thread` and `ThreadStart()` are underlined red, with no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` instead of `InvokeOnMainThread` or use a `Task`.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => { ... } );
```